# Torque induced by drilling machines

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, angular-velocity

A screw drilling machine, while constantly in use, delivers a torque on a screw. But if the drilling machine applies a constant torque on the screw, why does it, after a certain time period, look as if the screw is rotating at a constant angular speed. Souldn't it be accelerating constantly until the drilling machine has stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.  So assuming that you're not deceived by how the drill appears to be turning, there are two possible ways to address this:

- The torque delivered by the engine is not the only torque on the drill.
- The torque delivered by the engine is not constant.

When drilling into ground, the first is obviously true.  The drag from moving the material will manifest as a counter-torque on the drill.

The second will be true as well.  Since the device could be damaged by overspeed, there will be some sort of control or governor mechanism to limit the speed.  As the max speed is reached, the torque will be reduced.

Even without a governor, the engine itself will have severe limits on its ability to deliver torque.  If you look at the torque curve for a regular car (which also uses an internal combustion engine), you'll see that the ability to deliver torque falls off considerably at high RPMs.  So engines (and electric motors) should not be thought of as constant torque devices.

Answer (score 0):

A metalworking machine contains a electric motor which is adjustable for speed, to accommodate different materials, alloys, tool bits, etc.

The tool operator selects the desired rotating speed of the spindle to match the requirements of the task and then an automatic control system monitors that speed setpoint and furnishes enough voltage to the motor to hold its speed constant during the job.