# Why does a drill-bit rotate at a constant angular velocity

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation, angular-velocity

When we use an automatic screwdriver ie: screwdrilling machine, we set the controls of the machine in such a way so as to rotate the drill bit at a certain fixed speed.

But the point around which I can't wrap my head around is that if the screwdrilling machine is providing torque for the drill bit to rotate there has got to be an angular acceleration of the drill bit because of the equation $ T = I \alpha $ .

If there is angular acceleration then it ought to speed up it's rotation ( angular velocity) over time. Then why does the drillbit seem to be moving at a constant angular velocity.

Comment: Don't forget about friction

Comment: Closely related recent question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530198/torque-induced-by-drilling-machines/530202

Comment: Consider the situation as if the screwdrilling machine with the drillbit is spun in mid air. Because then also we observe that the drill bit spins at a constant angular velocity

Comment: @G.Smith  I read those answers but I think that the question that even though an $\alpha$ exists why is there a constant angular velocity , still remains unanswered

Comment: Yes but there is internal friction between the gears and other internals

Comment: *even though an $\alpha$ exists why is there a constant angular velocity* The answer is that $\alpha$ *doesn’t* exist. When the drill is drilling at a constant angular velocity, $\alpha$ and $T$ are *zero*. A constant angular velocity with a nonzero angular acceleration is a contradiction in terms. It is impossible by the definition of angular acceleration.

Comment: As the (perfectly good) answers explained, there is a counter-torque from the wood, and/or a governor to reduce the net torque to zero.

Comment: Ohh, ok thanks  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screw drilling machine has an automatic speed controller built in to it. When you set the speed you want, the control system maintains that speed for you by varying the voltage to the drive motor, and monitoring how fast it is turning at all times. In this regard, it's like the cruise control in your car.